# How to get the values using session in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I create a website using codeigniter with registration and login page with session the both are working fine but i need to save the datas in particular user using session and i need to get the values for the particular user in codeigniter. I am newer in codeigniter i dont know how to use the session value to get the particular user value and save the datas in particulate user.

I checked in google no tutorial is help for me can any one help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to load `session` library.Using

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

**OR** in `application/config/autoload.php` using

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Then you can `set` session item using

```
$this->session->set_userdata('name');
```

And `get` session item using

```
$this->session->userdata('name');
```

For more see docs [Codeigniter Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)